# Injecting data from two separate incoming requests

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, inject

I have a Java application that has an incoming **HTTP GET request** (part of a REST API). When the server receives this request it must maintain the connection open whilst it goes and perform some *external services*. The result of these *external services* is that a few seconds later a **completely separate** **incoming HTTP POST** request will arrive with some data.

At this point I need to inject the data from the second **incoming HTTP POST** into the response of the first **incoming HTTP GET request**.

I can allocate an ID to the original **incoming HTTP GET request** and have that ID be a present in the second **incoming HTTP POST**. So I do have a way of creating a 'bind' between the two requests. My question is how do I use this binding ID to tag the instance/thread of the original **incoming HTTP GET request** and then inject the data from the second **incoming HTTP POST** back into it?

I suspect it will be down the line of an observer/listener but I am unsure how to tag and identify the instances to make sure the correct data is injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a concurrent singleton class handling the two requests one after another and identifying respective request pairs by their ID - you could then also implement a timeout mechanism where you store the incoming time of the first request and after a given period of time discarding the first request for not becoming a zombie thread etc.

Comment: I like it! So effectively store a Singleton Map with the key as the id and the actual instance as the value.